# Checking the struct array is empty or not

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

ok I have an array of structs, (NOT array of pointers to structs), -lesson- is also a class that has some properties inside..

```
struct Mystruct{
    lesson* data;
    mystruct* next;
};    

class Myclass{
    public:
        Myclass();
        Mystruct getarray();
    private:
        Mystruct* array;
};
//in the myclass(); constructor I am doing;
Myclass* array = new Myclass[8];
```

I need to know that whether

```
array[i].next
```

is empty or not, since it is not an array of pointers to structs, I am not able to do so by saying;

```
if(array[i] == NULL)
```

or

```
if(&(array[i]) == NULL)
```

How can I do that, the answer that I am lookin for is NOT "it is an array of structs you simply cannot do this check, if it would be a pointer....bla bla". 
Please help me find a way, all answers and approaches are very appreciated..

****EDIT: let me clarify it for you, I need to check that;**

```
array[i].next = new lesson(//parameters);
```

This action is done or not, I need to know that whether the "next" object in the arrays [i]th element is initialized.
(array's [i]th element holds a linked list, I am searchin thru the list and adding objects to it, if the lists head is not empty, I have to find a way to figure that out and add objects at the end of the linked list)

How can I be more clear, but someones just clickin the *dislike* button instead of trying to help, this is a serious question not a troll, I am trying to be more clear as much as I can, but you guys are not helping, just clicking and leaving, what can I say more...:/

**I added MORE CODE for you to imagine the situation.**

Comment: So, by empty you mean that both pointers in the struct are null? Or just that they don't point to an object of the expected type?

Comment: Create a constructor for the `Mystruct` struct, where you set the pointers to `nullptr` (or `NULL`).

Comment: Can't tell what you are asking here, do you have an instance of `MyStruct`? `array[i].next` will not work because `array[i]` is a MyClass not a `MyStruct`.

Comment: I meant that someone is not set an object to that direction,for example ---array[i].next = new lesson(//parameters); ---

Comment: @Karavana: Per my example... you initialize your pointers in your constructor (which you do not currently do).

Comment: What is `Myclass` - show its definition. Is it somehow related to `Mystruct`?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Oh, I didn't even notice the forward declaration at first.  Kara, is that just a typo?  Why is the forward declaration there?

Comment: I edited the Code but dont know if it is any clear, if you can help from now on, it would be very helpful..

Answer (score 2):

> is empty or not,

Define "empty".  Do you mean uninitialized? If so then just initialize each element to some default value.  Initialize the pointers to `nullptr` (C++11) or `0` and then check before using them.  It makes no sense for an object to be "empty".

Also note that `MyClass` is... well, not a class at all. Anyway...

If you're just using the default constructor then what's the point?  When you allocate this memory it will be filled with default constructed objects, so...

```
struct Mystruct
{
    Mystruct()
      : data(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}

    lesson* data;
    myclass* next;
};
```

Now you properly initialize the pointers `x` and `y` to be null.

---

Per your edit...

> EDIT: let me clarify it for you, I need to check that;
>
> array[i].next = new lesson(//parameters);
>   this action is done or not, I need to know that whether the "next" object in the arrays [i]th element is initialized.

Right, so because we now properly initialize out member variables...

```
if(!array[i].next)
    // next is null, initialize it
```

Comment: I am askin that the arrays [i]th element's "next" object is initialized or not..

Comment: @Karavana: There is no magic solution.  You initialize your data properly and then you can check at a later time.

Comment: thank you for giving a sh*t and trying to help, the downvoters are clicked and left..

Comment: @Karavana: No problem, I gave you an upvote to help even things out a bit.  I don't know why people get so miffed at problems that seem trivial to them.  We were all beginners at some point.  Anyway, just initialize your member variables and you'll be good.

Comment: I have 6 .cpp files and 1 main.cpp in my project, ofc I cannot copy all the code here, in one of my .cpp's I have to check this condition and add elements at the end of my linked list, I just tried to draw a picture so that you can understand what I meant. thank you again btw..

Comment: @Karavana: Ok, but the definition of `Mystruct` and the subsequent forward declaration of `Myclass` makes things really confusing.  `Mystruct` isn't even used in your example, but I think I got what you are after regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Mystruct and Myclass in your question are the same type.

Just add empty() member function to your struct, and call it:

```
struct Mystruct{
    lesson* data;
    myclass* next;
    bool empty() const { return next == 0; }
};    

Myclass* array = new Myclass[8](); // extra () to make this array zeroed
//... some code
if (array[2].empty()) { ....; }
```

Or add global function empty():

```
struct Mystruct{
    lesson* data;
    myclass* next;
};    
bool empty(const Mystruct& o) const { return o.next == 0; }

Myclass* array = new Myclass[8](); // extra () to make this array zeroed
//... some code
if (empty(array[2])) { ....; }
```

Or just check this next member by hand:

```
struct Mystruct{
    lesson* data;
    myclass* next;
};    

Myclass* array = new Myclass[8](); // extra () to make this array zeroed
//... some code
if (array[2].next == 0) { ....; }
```

BTW, instead of comparing pointer to 0, compare it to nullptr (if only your compiler supports nullptr).

Comment: *"BTW, instead of comparing pointer to 0, compare it to nullptr (if only your compiler supports nullptr)."* or just `if(!some_ptr)` as that is guaranteed to work.  Also, it's better to just initialize these pointers to null in the constructor instead of providing an `empty()` function.  The problem is that their value is indeterminate, so checking against 0 is pretty useless unless they were explicitly zeroed outside after allocation.